# TypeError Cannot read property 'instantiations' of undefined

Tags: typescript

I am following a typescript [tutorial](https://ts.chibicode.com/todo/) and trying to run the following code but receive

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'instantiations' of undefined
```

The problem seems to stem from my `type Todo`. What am I doing wrong?

```
type Todo = Readonly<{
  id: number;
  text: string;
  done: boolean;
}>;
// Override the done property of Todo
type CompletedTodo = Todo & {
  readonly done: true;
};

function completeAll(todos: readonly Todo[]): CompletedTodo[] {
  return todos.map((todo) => ({
    ...todo,
    done: true
  }));
}

console.log(
  completeAll([
    { id: 1, text: "…", done: false },
    { id: 2, text: "…", done: true }
  ])
);
```

My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-cannon-kq3oc?file=/src/index.ts:0-416)

Comment: It works when I use it in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzlAvFAShAhkgdgGxAB4BvAKCigEsEAuKXAVwFsAjCAJwG4KpgIAHsHoBnYByq4A5j0p4I9VnDj5suHgF8AfDwD0uqAHkAbpwkJowABbR5UMBziQOoKHABmsRHDKhIUAGE4ZjBVfgR4JFQvKIAyKHJKDmw8Qih5enFGCE0eMndGXABjYCo4XCgi4NCIfgBBfHwACmBvEXpknHK0yLgAbQBdAEp6IJCwiAjvQYTeZOBGDgrWpBEAOmYsMCaW7yHULSgmxMooNfOVuAAaXjlyhT4ObN4NIaHNMjIq3BEVCDX8HApE1eFVxrUIA1mn1bglqHQoABGK58QTCKAAIkAZAQYlEZKDuLD4ETQDQ3U5wmj0ABMKP4Qno2Nx6XumSepN4wzI7zIQA).

Comment: Guess codesandbox behaves a bit differently. Will close the question because nothing seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codesandbox behaves a bit differently. Typescript playground runs the code fine.